# DirectShow: How to capture audio and video

Tags: directshow

I am looking for **a way to capture my desktop**. I came across something called `direct Show` but I cannot seem to get the syntax right on `ffmpeg`.

What can I do to capture the audio and video ?

I tried the syntax given in direct show site but not sure about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got mine to work and below i've given two examples of how you can do it and play it.

First one is

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="screen-capture-recorder":audio="virtual-audio-capturer" -vcodec h264_nvenc -f mpegts udp://10.1.0.0:1234
```

This will stream it in the same network in the udp link

play it by typing `ffplay udp://@10.1.0.0:1234`.
You can change the udp link to what you want. Try different variation so it work. or even type this into VLC, which will also make it work.

**2ND is**

`ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="screen-capture-recorder":audio="virtual-audio-capturer" -vcodec h264_nvenc output.mp4`

You will get a mp4 file with the recording. Just press `ctrl + c` to stop the recording. Or if you know how long to record for add `-t *seconds*`. Replace *seconds* with actual number of seconds you want to record for. just add the `-t` before the output file name.

Comment: Make sure you download the direct show setup first. maybe thats why its not working for you. you can do this command here to see if you have the audio and video capture: ```ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy```